# How do I display matplotlib.pyplot plots from a remote Ubuntu platform on a local Windows machine?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ubuntu, backend

There are alot of similar questions and answers to this one on this site.  But nothing that I find is working.  If I try the default backend, I get an error when I load `matplotlib.pyplot` to the effect that there is no `_tkinter` module.  I'm told to solve this by installing `python-tk`, but `pip` would not install it because " `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-tk.  No matching distribution found for python-tk`"  (Really?)  If I try the `"agg"` backend (`matplotlib.use('agg')`) everything looks fine until I try to display a plot, and nothing shows up -- no error message at all, just no display. I have tried the `GTK` backend and am told that I have to install the `pygtk` package.  But `pip` won't install it in Ubuntu because "`Building PyGTK using distutils is only supported on windows`."  I read somewhere about the `nbagg` backend, but it looks like it is going to need `IPython.display`, which `pip` won't install because, again, it can't find a version that satisfies ....  Is it really so hard to get `matplotlib` and `pyplot` working on a remote Ubuntu platform?  Anyone know what I can do?

UPDATE:  Am working with Ubuntu 18.04.6 and python 2.7.  I don't believe I will be able to change either one.

Comment: How are you connecting to that remote system? SSH, maybe something else?

Comment: Putty.  X forwarding definitely enabled.  xterm and similar stuff working just fine.

Comment: Which versions are you using?  Ubuntu and Python are the most important things to describe, as if these are recent it should "just work"

Comment: Think you're going to have to build things from source then.  That's ancient!

Comment: I'd suggest upgrading to more recent things as soon as possible.  I'd be very worried about security vulnerabilities accumulating in stuff that old.  Python 2.7 has been unmaintained for 3 years now.

Comment: @SamMason  Well, I'll do without then.  Thanks for saving me a bunch of work.  Sigh.  BTW, is it the ubuntu or the python that's the main problem, do you think?  Thanks.

Comment: They're both problematic!  From a security point of view I'd worry more about Ubuntu.  Upgrading that might fix the python issue as a side effect